# physics exploding

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create an egg to shatter when a cube from within expands bigger than the shape of the egg. As soon as the cube scale expands, the egg explodes like a firecracker went off. I'm just wanting it to crack and break apart just as the cube expands big enough to pierce the shell of the egg, and then it starts to fall apart. I'm using the RBDlabs addon, but I'm not using the exploding effect. All I've done is fractured the egg and gave it a rigid body and put a cube inside and gave it a rigid body and animated the scale of the cube. As you can see in the video, the egg explodes just as the cube scale changes, and the fact it's exploding is annoying. I just wanted it to crack and crumble apart in place.

[image]

Comment: Is the cube essential Alex?  If not the cell fracture can be organised to simply  crack and fall apart,  Cracks can also be progressively revealed with a little simple masking.  I'll go get an egg and do one.  Let's know about that cube.

Comment: I like to make content with my speedcube (rubik's cube) models for my social media. So I had the idea that one painted Easter egg out of a group of eggs would have my speedcube grow out of the egg and cause it to crack and fall apart under the pressure for a short animation.

Comment: Try removing the physics from the cube.  See how the egg behaves then.  Don't worry about the timing just yet.  The cell fracture can be set to occur at any frame.  If the Cell Fracture is still exploding the egg, I can explain how to overcome that with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this won't be exactly what you've got in mind but it should show you how to cure your problem.

This was done with Blender Vers 2.77 so masking for the crack(s) would have to be done differently.
Blender's internal masking should work if it's still available.

The crack(s) could be beveled curves and made to grow with their curve's Start and End sliders.  (Not to be confused with the keyframe Start & End settings)

[image]

The shell -

Actually there are two.  A duplicate of the original scaled up a little to wrap around and conceal the Cell- fracture segments.  The outer shell has no physics.

Cell-fractured segments on the other hand do and will want to fly apart if their abutting surfaces have any significant dimension. (adjacent edge area)  It's why they repel each other despite a minimal  'collision- margin' setting  in their physics.

The cube shouldn't have any physics at all because that would also affect CF segment behavior.

With the cube as scenery only, it can be scaled up and at the point of penetration or near to it, the CF activated.

The cell fracture by default treats the eggshell as solid throughout and segments accordingly will extend through to the shell's center.  That leavs us with thick chunks of egg lying around instead of a thin eggshell segments.  It also gives them large abutting surfaces for the physics to act on and send them apart.

To thin them out give the eggshell a 'Solidify' modifier but zoom up real close and adjust the thickness to as thin as you can, and yet still have the CF accept that.  If it doesn't it simply won't operate. Thicken the solidify up a whisker and try again.  Once you get that right 'Apply' the Solidify modifier.

When you do the cell fracture, take a look at the segments in WIREFRAME mode.  You'll see they are all thin and confined to the outer walls, not extending into the shell's interior.

[image]

When given physics set them to 'Mesh' and set their collision margin to 0.002 or less.  When the physics is activated (tick the Dynamic box with a keyframe) they should just collapse.

-================-

The cube -

There's not a lot to comment on other than to expand it and time the cell fracture's activation with it penetrating the shell.

The first thing you'll notice is the shell segments above the cube will fall right through.  To prevent this, place a (2D) plane on the cube's top surface and with the same dimensions.  Give that Passive RB physics and set it to 'Mesh' with a collision margin of 0.002 or less.

-=============-

The Crack -

That's a very thin plane subdivided with it's vertices pulled North & South to make a jagged line.

A shrinkwrap modifier was used to wrap it around the shell's exterior, and that 'Applied', or you could use a curve and 'Apply' it, or draw them with the grease pencil.

A mask was placed at it's front so it would be invisible initially.  That was then slid back to expose it's jagged length progressively up to where the shell starts to disintegrate.
The crack is then switched to invisible permanently in the Outliner.

[image]